# Are UDID registrations real

Tags: certificate, udid

There are services like https://udidregistrations.com where you can register you UDID and get Certificates and Provision profiles. Are they worth? What danger is there? Signing applications is real?

Why I ask: I want to "play" a little with Xcode and Objective-C and have the possibility to test on my iPhone, but don't want to pay 100$ just for playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the administrator from UDIDRegistrations.com. I want to state that we do not support piracy in any way shape or form. Any members that promote piracy are immediately banned.

We simply allow you to join our development team so you can sign your own developed applications and test them on your own iDevice. By extension of doing this, your iDevice is registered which will allow you to install betas granted you have downloaded the files yourself.

You can use Certificate & Provisioning to develop with Xcode and test on your registered device. Obviously, it cannot be submitted to the App Store unless you have your own developer account. But paying a fraction of the fee to start developing is well worth it!

Additionally you can use InstaSign and Zeusmos to sign these applications on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the description of udidregistrations.com makes me think that you can use Xcode to develop apps since you need to log in with a developer Apple ID in Xcode.

It seems like it's geared for people that want to download the new pre-release OS and get pirated apps to be re-signed by that developer. Unless they want to tell you the Apple ID and password that they are using to pay apple for the ability to register UDID - you'll likely be disappointed with the purchase.

Nothing on the UDID website seems technically wrong, but it sure seems against the terms Apple asks developers to adhere to and also seems very grey area at best and possibly something that Apple would shut down if the sale of UDID registrations or malware gets signed by that developer or anyone they resell their developer certificates to.